# FreeRTOS stack overflow hook

Tags: operating-system, embedded, hook, freertos

According to `FreeRTOS` documentation regarding stack overflow:

> The application must provide a stack overflow hook function if configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW is not set to 0. The hook function must
>   be called vApplicationStackOverflowHook(), and have the prototype
>   below:
>
> void vApplicationStackOverflowHook( TaskHandle_t xTask,signed char
>   *pcTaskName );

And in `FreeRTOS` the following prototype is defined inside `tasks.h` file:

```
 /* Callback function prototypes. --------------------------*/
 extern void vApplicationStackOverflowHook( xTaskHandle pxTask, signed char *pcTaskName );
```

So, I set `configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW` to 2 and implement the function
in my application code:

```
void vApplicationStackOverflowHook( xTaskHandle pxTask, signed char *pcTaskName )
{
    while (1)
    {
        /* my code. Prints stuff directly to the console*/
    }
}
```

My question is whether or not this implementation is correct? i.e, the hook implementation is in my application code, and the declaration in `tasks.h` remains untouched.

Comment: What is the cause for your doubt?  If it compiles and links and the correct function is called it is correct - i..e the compiler/linker will soon tell you if it were not.  When you get a stack overflow, be aware that your code is likely to crash in ways that cause this function not to be called - the check is only performed on a context switch and the code may not get that far after a stack overflow.

Comment: Any reason you use the uncommon `2` which is not the standard boolean value in C? And how should **we** tell youi it is correct? It is **your** code after all. Just note there is no console in typical FreeRTOS applications.

Comment: Looks good to me. But as Clifford says, if your stack has overflowed anything could happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right to me.  You will find many, many, many examples in the FreeRTOS/Demo directory of the FreeRTOS download.  The rationale for using 2 rather than 1 is here: http://www.freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html